# Firing events from state machine's onEntry function

Tags: c, state-machine

I am doing a state machine which is supposed to evaluate some conditions on entrance to a new state and, depending on those conditions, appropriate new event should be triggered. My first thought was to send event from `onEntry` function but then I have indirect recursion which is, as far as I think (maybe I am wrong), a bit dangerous (because of the possibility of the stack overflow error).

Here is the sample code (**note** that it is only an example of state machine pattern **I need to use**):

**state_machine.h**

```
typedef enum State
{
    STATE_A,
    STATE_B,
    STATE_C
} State;

typedef enum Event
{
    EVENT_A,
    EVENT_B,
    EVENT_C,
    EVENT_D,
    EVENT_E,
    EVENT_F
} Event;

void handleEvent(Event event);
```

**state_machine.c**

```
#include "state_machine.h"

static void switchState(State newState, Event event);

static void onExit(Event event);

static void onEntry();

static State currentState = STATE_A;

void handleEvent(Event event)
{
    switch (currentState)
    {
    case STATE_A:
        switchState(STATE_B, event);
        break;
    case STATE_B:
        switchState(STATE_C, event);
        break;
    case STATE_C:
        switchState(STATE_A, event);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void switchState(State newState, Event event)
{
    onExit(event);
    currentState = newState;
    onEntry();
}

void onExit(Event event)
{
    // ...
}

void onEntry()
{
    switch (currentState)
    {
    case STATE_A:
        if (condition)
        {
            handleEvent(EVENT_C);
        }
        else
        {
            handleEvent(EVENT_D);
        }
        break;
    case STATE_B:
        // ...
        break;
    case STATE_C:
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

My second solution to this problem is having a `nextState` variable which would be set in `onEntry` function (instead of `handleEvent` call). And then on top of `handleEvent` function I would have sth like this:

```
if (nextEvent != EVENT_NULL)
{
    event = nextEvent;
    nextEvent = EVENT_NULL;
}
```

Now, my question is this: what is better approach and/or what is usually done in these kind of situations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In most practical cases (parsers), the number of state-changing *events* per state  is small, the default action will be: "stay in this state". So, a big `switch(current_state) { ... }` will be easier to maintain than a `swich(event) { ...}`  In more complex cases, you can go table-driven and use(f)lex to generate the tables for you.

Comment: @joop Sorry, but can you be more precise? I didn't get the point.

Comment: Also, your function-based approch will also  make *real work* (such as maintaining buffers, think yytext[] ...) difficult, because you'll have to pass these to the worker functions, or use global variables ...

Comment: Why not create a queue for events and have a loop in which you process the events (possibly in its own thread) one at a time? Then you can just enqueue events externally or internally whenever you have to/want to.

Comment: What @Dr.P3pp3r says.  Please try to avoid any bodges.  A state-machine is an excellent design for many requirements but you MUST implement it correctly, ie. one event at a time.

Comment: I was also thinking about some sort of queue but is that common approach?

Comment: @PeMaCN very common, yes.  I use it often - one thread specifically to run the state-machine using events queued in on a producer-consumer queue.  Please believe me when I say that any kind of bodge/deviation/shortcut/whatever from one-event-at-a-time WILL go disastrously wrong and be VERY difficult to debug.